# Actions on Google API v2 using c# webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I currently have an app running on actions on google using API.AI.  I have modified all the response members to be camelCase as suggested and got it working.  Now I am trying to return a basic card, but I can not figure out how to properly return it.

Does anyone have the most basic JSON response, returning a basic card to the Google assistant?

currently, the most basic v2 API response I can have is the following:

```
{
    speech: "",
    displayText: "",
    data: {
        google: {
            expectUserResponse: true,
            isSsml: true,
            permissionsRequest: null
        }
    },
    contextOut: [ ],
    source: "webhook"
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting when you try to return a basic card? Can you show the JSON you were using to return the card?

Answer (score 3):

I have some Gists showing the JSON responses [here](https://gist.github.com/NicoSB/ab98b91f033b9be6e09223f597cfae40).

Right now, it includes Lists, Basic Card and Carousel, but I will add Transactions hopefully soon. Hope it might help somehow

Comment: Hi, Any idea on how to parse responses from JSON file instead of writing actual `nodejs` code?

Comment: Hi, I'm no C# developer (doing the stuff in Java using Jackson), so I can't really tell you what the best practice for C# is, but maybe checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of parsing JSON. I thought there should be a native (built-in) method for creating RichResponses from JSON.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use for Voice Tic Tac Toe

```
"google": {
      "expect_user_response": true,
      "rich_response": {
        "items": [
          {
           "simple_response": {
              "text_to_speech": "Your move was top. I moved left"
            }
          },
          {
            "basic_card": {
              "image": {
                "url": "https://server/010200000.png",
                "accessibility_text": "Tic Tac Toe game board"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I ran the facts about google action and looked at the fulfillment JSON output to learn how to do this.

https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-facts-about-google-nodejs

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need!

Comment: Cool, the API interface is a bit different than using Google home directly.
NiteLordz Can you mark this answer as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Note that all responses *must* include at least one, and no more than two, `simple_response` items.